# Could you check it's possible (Selenium python automation + PHP)

Tags: python, php, selenium, yii

Our system is developed with PHP and one of our coworkers developed Amazon automation program with Python.
I am wondering if it's possible to integrate together ?
if it is please recommend what ways i can do this

https://github.com/jasonminsookim/order_automation/blob/master/src/amzn.py
Here's code Amazon automation program

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. What exactly is the scope of the "integration" you're looking for. Python with selenium will work for something like automated testing, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That code is automated for ordering on Amazon 
I am wondering how can i get data from Python code and also receive data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but I would weigh what you have available to you and go from there. The tempfile solution is the most general, and is a common interface pattern for any two or more languages, but you can get more exotic if performance is a major concern with pipes.

### Temp-file

I guess the most rudimentary way to do this would be to have the python file output some data to a file that can be read in by php or vice versa.

Something like creating a directory called `/orders` where php put's in `order.json` files and python takes those in, reads them and gets the result, then puts it back as a `order-result.json`. Essentially a temp-file system to communicate between the two.

### Pipes

Alternatively depending on your setup you could pipe results into php from python with something like the `subprocessing` module and a php CLI that interfaces with your DB.